# Removing SQL CE Dependencies - Error 0152 - No Entity Framework provider ADO.NET System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net, sql-server-ce

I know there are a number of topics around this error, but the situation my team has right now is a bit different.

We are working with an older project and want to streamline it. Among other things, the new program should technically no longer require SQL CE. However, currently it still requires SQL CE to be installed and we are trying to work out why.

We have already tried removing all dependencies and packages from all subprojects of the project, such as Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact and EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact, but we still get the following error on certain pages of the website the project outputs:

```
2018-01-17 06:49:18,217 ERROR - Could not select provider.
2018-01-17 06:49:18,217 ERROR - An exception occurred while initializing the database. See the InnerException for details.
2018-01-17 06:49:18,219 DEBUG -    at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<InitializeDatabase>b__4(InternalContext c)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
   at System.Linq.Queryable.Select[TSource,TResult](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 selector)
   at FGCI.Database.EntityFramework.FGEntityTable`1.get_Provider()
2018-01-17 06:49:18,219 ERROR - Inner Exception:
2018-01-17 06:49:18,219 ERROR - Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
(0,0) : error 0152: No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0'. Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.
2018-01-17 06:49:18,219 DEBUG -    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Loader.ThrowOnNonWarningErrors()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Loader.LoadItems(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 sourceFilePaths)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Loader..ctor(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 sourceFilePaths, Boolean throwOnError, IDbDependencyResolver resolver)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Init(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 filePaths, Boolean throwOnError, IDbDependencyResolver resolver, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest, DbProviderFactory& providerFactory, String& providerInvariantName, String& providerManifestToken, Memoizer`2& cachedCTypeFunction)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection..ctor(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.XDocumentExtensions.GetStorageMappingItemCollection(XDocument model, DbProviderInfo& providerInfo)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.Diff(XDocument sourceModel, XDocument targetModel, Lazy`1 modificationCommandTreeGenerator, MigrationSqlGenerator migrationSqlGenerator, String sourceModelVersion, String targetModelVersion)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.IsModelOutOfDate(XDocument model, DbMigration lastMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClassc.<Update>b__b()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`2.InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.<>c__DisplayClassa`1.<CreateInitializationAction>b__9()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action)
2018-01-17 06:49:18,220 DEBUG - Out: Entity_Table'.get_Provider
```

By all means, this program should no longer require SQLCE. And yet, it looks to me as though there's still some reference to SQL CE somewhere, but I just can't find it, and I'm at my wit's end here.

Does anyone have any advice as to how we might be able to resolve this? Once again, our goal is to find and get rid of all legacy dependencies the project has on SQL CE.

---

UPDATE:

I found the following EMX related file in the project. I can't make out anything suspicious in here either, but maybe I'm missing something.

```
-- --------------------------------------------------
-- Entity Designer DDL Script for SQL Server 2005, 2008, 2012 and Azure
-- --------------------------------------------------
-- Date Created: 07/15/2015 19:11:12
-- Generated from EDMX file: C:\Users\██████\Source\Workspaces\██████\Main\██████\Implementation\Net\██████\MetaDataModel.edmx
-- --------------------------------------------------

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF;
GO
USE [██████];
GO
IF SCHEMA_ID(N'dbo') IS NULL EXECUTE(N'CREATE SCHEMA [dbo]');
GO

-- --------------------------------------------------
-- Dropping existing FOREIGN KEY constraints
-- --------------------------------------------------


-- --------------------------------------------------
-- Dropping existing tables
-- --------------------------------------------------

IF OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[MetaData]', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[MetaData];
GO

-- --------------------------------------------------
-- Creating all tables
-- --------------------------------------------------

-- Creating table 'MetaData'
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MetaData] (
    [IntegratorId] varchar(100)  NOT NULL,
    [Name] int  NOT NULL,
    [Count] int  NOT NULL,
    [Value] varchar(255)  NOT NULL
);
GO

-- --------------------------------------------------
-- Creating all PRIMARY KEY constraints
-- --------------------------------------------------

-- Creating primary key on [IntegratorId], [Name], [Count] in table 'MetaData'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MetaData]
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_MetaData]
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([IntegratorId], [Name], [Count] ASC);
GO

-- --------------------------------------------------
-- Creating all FOREIGN KEY constraints
-- --------------------------------------------------

-- --------------------------------------------------
-- Script has ended
-- --------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have an EDMX file that has the SQLCE provider name included, you will need to rebuild that for SQL Server

Comment: Hmm, the only think related to EDMX in this project appears to be a file called "MetaDataModel.edmx.sql", which would appear to be an sql script created from an edmx file. I can't find anything suspicious in there, but maybe I am missing something. I'll post it in my  original question above as an update.

Comment: That script file is not relevant, as you assumed. Feel free to share your projct (privately) and I will have a look